# setSystemUIVsibility full screen disables when using Spinner

Tags: android

I am using

```
View root = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
root.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

to make my app full screen. It works fine, except when I use a `Spinner`. As soon as I dropdown the options, the system bar appears again. I tried using `setSystemUIVisibility()` on the `Spinner` to no effect.

How can I get my app to be full screen all the time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this code instead:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: I love it when stuff can be simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can be done through styles

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```