# How to keep full screen when click spinner android?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, spinner, fullscreen

In my android app I use a spinner. App runs in full screen mode. But when I touch spinner to see the dropdown list, navigation bar appear. It disappears only after selecting an item of dropdown list. Can any body tell me how to keep full screen when click spinner? I've tried this code but it doesn't help me
http://devmobapps.blogspot.com/2011/09/bug-in-android-or-problem-with-spinner.html

I'm using Lollipop device. Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this flag, as suggested [in this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20146590/5466997). Adding it right after setContentView(...) worked like a charm for me:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

As [`FLAG_FULLSCREEN`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_FULLSCREEN) is deprecated starting from API level 30, you can use [`FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS):

You can also call it when touching the spinner

```
mSpinner.setOnTouchListener((view, motionEvent) -> { 
    getWindow().setFlags(FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```
List<String> spinnerArray =  new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i< 10; i++)
    spinnerArray.add("item " + i);

Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this, Spinner.MODE_DIALOG);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I did not try it in Lollipop device, but it should work